# How do I read mentions in fb api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

When I get a certain status in "/{status id}" api call, I get the message stripped from the mentions. How can I read the mentions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the field `message_tags` will give an array of mentioned users/pages in that post](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/posts?fields=with_tags,message_tags)

Example:

```
"message_tags": {
        "13": [
          {
            "id": "92689703737",
            "name": "Tumblr",
            "type": "page",
            "offset": 13,
            "length": 6
          }
        ]
         }
```

Comment: it works only when including user_id:
/{user_id}_{post_id}?fields=message_tags
not with just /{post_id}?fields=message_tags
but that's still good for me! thanks

Comment: also, it doesn't work for the not-so-new facebook "feeling" statuses, like "is watching @mention"